# How to Display UI Notification Window in Terminated Mode Using Firebase Messaging

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-local-notification

i am using both plugins `firebase_messaging` & `flutter_local_notifications`

my code looks like following

```
 Future main() async {
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   await Firebase.initializeApp();
   initFirebaseMessaging();
 }

 Future<void> onBackGroundNotiRecived(RemoteMessage message)async {
   final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
   const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
   AndroidNotificationDetails(
     'your_channel_id',
     'your_channel_name',
     channelDescription: 'your_channel_description',
     importance: Importance.max,
     priority: Priority.high,
     showWhen: false,
   );
   const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);

   await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
     0,
     message.notification!.title!,
     message.notification!.body!,
     platformChannelSpecifics,
   );

 }

 Future<void> initFirebaseMessaging()async{
   initFlutterLocalNotifications();
   final notificationInstance = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
   await notificationInstance.requestPermission();
   FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(onBackGroundNotiRecived);
 }

 Future<void> initFlutterLocalNotifications()async{
   final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
   const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
   const InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid);
   await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
 }
```

I receive notifications in both background and terminated modes as expected. However, I've noticed that the UI dialog appears only when the app is in the background. In the terminated mode, I still receive notifications, but the UI dialog doesn't show.

How can I ensure that the UI dialog appears in both background and terminated modes when using Firebase Messaging in Flutter?

Please note that my initial intention in using flutter_local_notifications was the expectation that it would continue to display the notification UI window even when the application is in the terminated mode. However, I encountered difficulties in achieving this with that library. Does Firebase Messaging handle this task ?

Any insights, solutions, or recommendations on achieving consistent UI dialog appearance for notifications would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your assistance!